# Remote creation of Custom actions in Thunar

Tags: linux, centos, salt-stack

I'm using Thunar as file browser for a linux network composed of 100 CentOS 7.2 machines. We are managing the installation of those workstations with a PXE server and SaltStack installation. 
I need to create those custom actions during the installation.

Currently, Thunar is installed on every workstations, the script is available on a share but I need to create the custom action on each machine. Open Thunar, Edit > Create custom actions and it launches my script in xterm for the selected folder:

```
xterm -e "/path/to/my/script.sh %f"
```

**Is there a way to create Thunar's custom actions from command lines or by editing a file so that I will be able to launch them through Salt cmd.run?**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that those Custom actions are store in this file:

```
cat ~/.config/Thunar/uca.xml
```

Here is an example of the syntaxe:

```
<?xml encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"?>
<actions>
<action>
    <icon>script.png</icon>
    <name>My custom action</name>
    <unique-id>1479309009025049-2</unique-id>
    <command>xterm -e &quot;/path/to/my/script.sh %f&quot;</command>
    <patterns>*</patterns>
    <startup-notify/>
    <directories/>
    <audio-files/>
    <image-files/>
    <other-files/>
    <text-files/>
    <video-files/>
</action>
</actions>
```

That way, I can create this template file and copy it in the user folder.